# In Oracle Apex, is there a set of hot keys to activate the Run Command?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In Oracle Apex SQL Workshop, is there a set of hot keys to activate the Run Command?  I've researched this online and have not found an answer.  It seems laborious to have to type out my query and then have to use my mouse to click on Run, when hot keys can help keep my hands on the keyboard.  I'm using a Mac and typically through Firefox.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Workshop? Ctrl-Enter

If you have multiple queries, highlight the relevant query first.